# Using encrypted SSH key generated by PuTTYgen when connecting via SSH with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, window, private-key

I generated my public/private key couple with PuTTYgen, and now I want to use them to connect to a remote Linux host via SSH. However, PuTTYgen prompted me to save the private key "with a password" (I guess it means encrypted), and I did. What steps should I take to use said key to connect via SSH to a server?

Comment: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.71/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-gettingready or if you're using PuTTY on Windows (which is the only one that normally uses that capitalization) open the Help window, select "Using public keys for SSH authentication" then "8.3 ..." PS: the standard wording is key 'pair' not 'couple'.

Answer (score 0):

In PuTTY Configuration window, go to *Connection > SSH > Auth*. And there in the [*"Private key file for authentication"* box](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-privkey), specify your private key. It does not matter if it is encrypted or not. The procedure is the same. The difference is only, whether you get prompted for the passphrase or not.

[image]

---

Or load the key into [Pageant (PuTTY authentication agent)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter9.html). This way, you will get prompted for the passphrase only once, not every time you login.